# Using ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider, how do I store my own per-user data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using the ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider. So, there's an `aspnet_Users` table that has details of each of my users. (Actually, the `aspnet_Membership` table seems to contain most of the actual data).

I now want to store some per-user information in my database, so I thought I'd just create a new table with a `UserId` (GUID) column and an FK relationship to `aspnet_Users`. However, I then discovered that I can't easily get access to the `UserId` since it's not exposed via the membership API. (I know I can access it via the `ProviderUserKey`, but it seems like the API is abstracting away the internal `UserID` in favor of the `UserName`, and I don't want to go too far against the grain).

So, I thought I should instead put a `LoweredUserName` column in my table, and create an FK relationship to `aspnet_Users` using that. Bzzzt. Wrong again, because while there is a unique index in `aspnet_Users` that *includes* the `LoweredUserName`, it also includes the `ApplicationId` - so in order to create my FK relationship, I'd need to have an `ApplicationId` column in my table too.

At first I thought: fine, I'm only dealing with a single application, so I'll just add such a column and give it a default value. Then I realised that the `ApplicationId` is a GUID, so it'd be a pain to do this. Not *hard* exactly, but until I roll out my DB I can't predict what the GUID is going to be.

I feel like I'm missing something, or going about things the wrong way. What am I *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for the ProfileProvider which let's you associate any arbitrary information you wish with the user.

[ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

**ADDITION** If the built-in ProfileProvider will not suit your needs, then you might consider implementing your own ProfileProvider by writing a class that derives from `System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider`. This would enable you to write something that avoids the serialization issues you mentioned in your comment.

[Implementing a Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**ADDITION** Note about the SqlMembershipProvider. You are indeed correct that the Membership classes are really keyed on username even though the schema is keyed on UserId. This is frankly one of my pet peeves about the SqlMembershipProvider classes. This actually creates problem in a multi-application environment where you want a single user store but independent application role lists.

My recommendation would be to key on UserId since it is, as you mentioned, the primary key of the aspnet_Users table and is used in all the foreign key relationships and it is a single value. If you key on LowerUsername (and ApplicationId), and the username changes, you'll need to have cascade update enabled so that the change ripples to your custom tables.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the data I need to store would sit well in serialized format. I'll need to do joins with various other tables that I already have in my database. I'd prefer to have my user data in tables that I can efficiently run queries against. So while I can see a use for Profile storage, it doesn't suit my situation. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

To do this, you can implement a profile provider.  Its not very difficult.  You will basically set up your user specific settings like this:

(web.config):

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="MyProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipCnnStr" applicationName="MyApp" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"/>
    </providers>
    <properties>
        <add name="EmployeeId" type="String" />
        <group name="UserSettings">
            <add name="IsSandboxMode" type="Boolean" defaultValue="false" />
            <add name="Shortcuts" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.string]" />
        </group>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Thomas' answer - I don't want to use Profile storage, I want to use a real database table. Thanks anyway, and +1 for the detail.

Comment: In that case, just as Thomas has said, you should write your own custom provider that uses your database.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at adding simple data tied to your users, such as added profile properties, you should look into [Personalization](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3520226/ASPNET-20-Profile-Simple-User-Personalization-for-Your-Web-Apps.htm).

Example, if you want to store a person's mother's maiden name as a part of their profile information you can do so using this feature.

It probably isn't the right choice for complex data, but it's a start.

Comment: You all answered at the same time with valid response so +1.

Comment: I should have said at the outset that I do have a whole bunch of existing database tables, and I need to be able to store my (complex) user data in a table that I can join with. So, Profiles is not really going to be suitable. +1 for your (appropriate) caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Write .cs file like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FirstNameTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(Profile.FirstName);
        LastNameTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(Profile.LastName);

    }

}
```

and web.config

```
 <profile>
  <providers>
      <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="LastName" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="MemberId" defaultValue="0" type="System.Int32"/>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```